# Cosmological horizon and Hawking/Unruh radiation?

Tags: cosmology, event-horizon, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

I have two questions about cosmological horizons and their emission of radiation

1. The first one is:

There are some authors that propose that dark energy or the accelerated expansion of the universe would "decay" meaning that the cosmological horizon of the universe would evaporate (e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6560872)

In principle, as the photons would not have an infinite space to escape (they would only be free to travel inside the "observable universe" space) they would get reabsorbed and no net evaporation should occur

But imagine that through some mechanism we managed to retain all the photons radiated by the horizon. Would it now evaporate? Would the horizon gradually recede to infinity? Wouldn't it still be radiating as it recedes?

2. My second question is:

I was discussing with a physicist how does the cosmological horizon relate with Hawking/Unruh radiation and he said that he did not think that a cosmological horizon would radiate. In particular, he said

> Hawking radiation is not “emitted by the horizon”: it exists because the past differs from the future: Gravitational contraction is “continuing” (witness the title of the Oppenheimer-Snyder paper) and therefore, the asymptotic behavior of quantum fields in the infinite past vs. the infinite future is not the same. (See Hawking’s 1974 paper; contrary to what he—or his ghostwriter—wrote in his popular book, the horizon is barely mentioned in the paper proper, key to the argument is this past-future asymmetry and continuing collapse). Unruh radiation exists because the Fourier-decomposition of a field into elementary oscillators is not the same in inertial vs. accelerating reference frames, and what is a ground state with no radiation for an inertial observer may be an excited state, detected as radiation, by the accelerating observer. A cosmological horizon exists in an expanding universe even without acceleration, though of course your point is that without acceleration, in the infinite future everything becomes visible to an observer, whereas with acceleration, some things will forever remain behind the horizon. Does this imply Hawking-type radiation? I don’t think so, but I don’t know to be honest. The reason why I don’t think so is that a) the universe remains spatially homogeneous, so there’s no gravitational vacuum polarization, and b) the observer is not accelerating with respect to some inertial ground state. Again I stress, Hawking/Unruh radiation is not coming from the horizon proper. (Among other things, the peak wavelength of Hawking radiation is ~20 times the Schwarzschild radius.)

I haven't ever heard his explanation for this from any other physicist. Is he right? Would there be radiation or not when there is a cosmological horizon?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, questions should focus on one question at a time. I don't know how to answer your first question, so I'll focus on the second one.

Indeed, your physicist friend is mostly right. Hawking radiation *is* about the difference between asymptotic past and future. However, he seems to miss out on the fact that the Unruh effect is a bit more subtle than just a difference in the definition of particles between inertial and accelerated observers. It was shown in the early 1990s by Kay and Wald that you can get a generalized notion of an accelerating observer (technically, a static observer outside a bifurcate Killing horizon) and these sorts of observers would also measure particles with a thermal spectrum. This is the case for radiation outside an eternal black hole and for cosmological horizons.

Shortly, there should be radiation from a cosmological horizon, but the key point is that its origin is quite different from the origin of the Hawking effect due to a few subtleties.